# Looping in to insert bulk data in Oracle is throwing out of memory exception

Tags: c#, oracle, bulkinsert

I have a file with 9 million to 13 million records. As the list has a limit size I have broken the code into chunks of 1 million records and trying to insert the record.

Here is code to read and break the file in chunks:

```
public static void InsertBulkData(string file)
    {
        List<FileData> lstFileData = new List<FileData>();
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
                {
                    string line = string.Empty;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        FileData obj = new FileData();
                        obj.Property1= line.Substring(5, 9).Trim();
                        obj.Property2= line.Substring(19, 40).Trim();

                        lstFileData.Add(obj);
                        if (lstFileData.Count == 1000000)
                        {
                            InsertDataIntoDatabase(lstFileData);
                            lstFileData = null;
                            GC.Collect();
                            lstFileData = new List<FileData>();

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now we are getting in the loop 9 times. But when i comes to saving of data it saves for the first time only. rest 8 times it throws exception.

```
  private static void InsertDataIntoDatabase(List<FileData> lstFileData)
    {
        String query = @"INSERT INTO table
                                        (
                                          PrimaryCol,
                                          Column1,
                                          Column2

                                        )
                                        VALUES
                                        (
                                          primaryCol.NEXTVAL,
                                          :Property1,
                                          :Property2,
                                          )";
        using (OracleConnection Conn = new OracleConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString();
                Conn.Open();
                using (var command = Conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.BindByName = true;
                    // In order to use ArrayBinding, the ArrayBindCount property
                    // of OracleCommand object must be set to the number of records to be inserted
                    command.ArrayBindCount = lstFileData.Count;
                    command.Parameters.Add(":Property1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, lstFileData.Select(c => c.Property1).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    command.Parameters.Add(":Property2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, lstFileData.Select(c => c.Property2).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Conn.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Exception is:" + ex.InnerException);
            }
        }
    }
```

So After first iteration we getting error in command.ExecuteNonQuery(). Can any one tell why and what is the possible solution?

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: System out of memory exception

Comment: i think use big size of memory in create  lstFileData in InsertBulkData method empty your list in end of each step instead om new

Comment: for the first time it insert but next time it throws error. We have chunks of 1M if we create chunks of 2M and insert all together it will insert but if we try to insert in loop then it is throwing error.

Comment: already did that. If you see I have assign it to null and also collected the space calling garbage collector.

Comment: clear assign to null an create line only set empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163769/discussion-between-anirudh-agarwal-and-hasan-fathi).

Comment: 9-13 million records?? Oracle provides utilities for bulk loading data - SQL\*Loader and external tables. Why not use one of those instead of trying to build your own tool? [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/toc.htm)

Comment: Actually we have a text file and each line has data that we need to exact using sub string

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the use of a buffer that reaches its maximum size. Moreover, if you use successive inserts, you will have performance problems. You should use another method (with bulk copy). Here is a sample code:

```
  public static void BulkCopy(string connectionString, DataTable dataTableToSend, string SQLTableName)
        {
            SqlConnection connexion = null;

            try
            {
                connexion = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                BulkCopy(connexion, dataTableToSend, SQLTableName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                connexion?.Close();
                connexion?.Dispose();
            }
        }

int Modulo=0;

//Create a datatable MyDataTable with same structure of your table in database
// you can do : select * from MyTable where 1<>1 with command for get structured dataset (and datatable)


 using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.UTF8))
 {
     while ((Line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         counter++;

         DataRow newrow = MyDataTable.NewRow();


         //Set value
         newrow["I_ID"] = counter;
         newrow["L_NomFichier"] = FileObj.Name;
         newrow["D_CreationFichier"] = FileObj.LastWriteTime;
         newrow["L_Ligne"] = Line.DBNullIfNullOrEmpty();
         newrow["D_DATCRE"] = newrow["D_DATMAJ"] = DateTime.Now;
         newrow["C_UTICRE"] = newrow["C_UTIMAJ"] = GlobalParam.User;

         MyDataTable.Rows.Add(newrow);


         if (Modulo % 1000)
         {
         SqlHelper.BulkCopy(DBAccess.CONN_STRING, MyDataTable, "YOURTABLENAME");

         MyDataTable.Rows.Clear();

         }


     }

     SqlHelper.BulkCopy(DBAccess.CONN_STRING, MyDataTable, "YOURTABLENAME");

     MyDataTable.Rows.Clear();

     file.Close();
 }
```